# Can the quartz xml scheduling data file contain only triggers?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Do I have to define jobs for each trigger in the xml file, or can my xml file only have triggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the jobs the triggers relate to are already in the scheduler, then it will process as expected, without errors.  If the jobs referred to by the triggers don't exist in the scheduler you will get an exception when the file is processed.

For the jobs to already be in the scheduler the jobs must either already have triggers (in the scheduler) or must have their "durable" flag set to "true" - which lets them exist outside of the lifespan of their triggers.